# File-level read permission in Azure DevOps is not working

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops, tfvc

I have this team project in Azure DevOps (previously known as VSTS):

```
$\TempProjectA
```

I have this developer that can log into Azure DevOps and develop code:

```
username: first_developer@example-company.com
password: *****
```

I have this group that is called `SingleFileReaders`, and I've added `first_developer@example-company.com` to this group.

Then using Visual Studio's Source Control Explorer, I've browsed to `$\TeamProjectA\FileToBeShared.java`, right clicked on it, using Advanced menu I managed to get to Security pop-up. And there, I allowed the read option.

Now I login as `first_developer@example-company.com` into Visual Studio, but I don't see that file. In fact, I don't see `TeamProjectA`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You Should add the developer to the Project Team members, with contributor role.

[Follow here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-users-team-project?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#add-users-to-a-project), Since the UI is changed there are some difficulties to find the securities/adding user configuration in Azure DevOps

**Security**

[image]

**Contributor role to access the Source codes**

[image]

Comment: Contributor role gives access to everything. I tested that. I tested `{team name}` role too. Shows everything to me. I don't want other files to be visible.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli I think without adding a member to that project team, the member will not able to view anything related to that project.First try to add the developer to the team project with 'reader' role then you can able to see the project from that developer credentials

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's stuck in this point, the trick is to give `View project-level information` permission to your role/user first. Using built-in roles is not helpful as they have permissions much more than what I wanted. They give access to all files, at least read-only permission.